# Permission denied while creating a symbolic link

Tags: mysql, unix, permissions, homebrew, symlink

I am installing mysql using homebrew for Mac OS X. Once the installation completes these options are given in the terminal:

```
To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mysql.server start
```

So what I would like to do is have mysql started at login but when I enter the command I get permission denied like so:

```
$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

ln: /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions as to why this may be occuring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html)?

```
$ sudo ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue while trying to run `ln -s /Applications/ngrok ngrok`. It returns permission denied. That means you need to allow Administrator to delegate a user to perform the operation. By prepending `sudo` will give that privilege and the system will prompt you for administrator password. `sudo ln -s /Applications/ngrok ngrok`

For [more information](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3322504/selectively-deploying-your-superpowers-on-linux.html) on `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on a web server where I have limited access (no sudo), so what worked for me was putting the symbolic link under /home//bin instead. I was able to install custom apps that I needed and setup them to work globally in this way. Hope this might help someone.